Modify SecurityFilterChain to allow access from certain IPs only
Currently I have the following method which requires a username and password for all endpoints under /actuator/** and all other pages are accessible without user authentication.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").authenticated();
                    auth.anyRequest().permitAll();
                })
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}

How can the method be modified in a way that the current functionality is preserved, but also to allow access from a list of IP addresses and traffic from all other IP addresses would get blocked/denied? The application is load balanced and I only want the IP address of the load balancer and the IP addresses of developers to be able to access the apps on the replica web servers.

This question is similar to: Matching IP address with authorizeHttpRequests. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it is briefly mentioned here in the migration guide from spring 5.8 to spring 6.x https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_migrate_hasipaddress_to_accessauthorizationmanager

This is what I came up with, which looks like it achieves what I was looking for
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private static final List<String> ALLOWED_IPS = List.of("127.0.0.1", "11.11.11.11");

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    // Restrict access to "/actuator/**" based on authentication and IP address
                    auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").access((authentication, context) -> {
                        String remoteIp = context.getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
                        return ALLOWED_IPS.contains(remoteIp)
                                ? new AuthorizationDecision(authentication != null && authentication.get().isAuthenticated())
                                : new AuthorizationDecision(false);
                    });

                    // Allow all other requests from specific IPs
                    auth.requestMatchers(request ->
                            {
                                return ALLOWED_IPS.contains(request.getRemoteAddr());
                            }
                    ).permitAll(); // Permit traffic from allowed IPs

                    // Deny all other requests (this is the default behavior)
                    auth.anyRequest().denyAll();
                })
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

